# CMake preload script for cache

Tags: build, cmake

I fire cmake with the -C mysettings.cmake.

The content of myfile.cmake is

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "C:/install/mylib" STRING)
```

Everything is generated but it seems the -C mysettings.cmake variable is not set. It is still installed in the default directory.

Cmake prints the message "loading initial cache file ../../script/cmake/mysettings.cmake"
without any error.

The full call:

```
cmake -C ../../script/cmake/mysettings.cmake -G "Visual Studio 9 2008" ../../source/mylib
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [CMake manual](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#opt%3a-Cinitial-cache):

> The given file should be a CMake script containing SET commands that
>   use the CACHE option, not a cache-format file.

So your `myfile.cmake` [needs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3aset) to look something like this:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "C:/install/mylib" CACHE PATH "")
```