# Global default settings for cmake

Tags: makefile, build, cmake, gnu-make

Is there anything similar to `MAKEFLAGS` environment variable for `cmake`, to set some global defaults like `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no similar environment variable for CMake. Everything you can set through environment variables in CMake is documented [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-env-variables.7.html).

But you could use a the ["preload cache" `-C` option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options) and put all reoccurring settings in an appropriate script (see e.g. [CMake preload script for cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597673/cmake-preload-script-for-cache)).